# Custom message in facebook notification not working

Tags: facebook, notifications, apprequests

I have gone through many question raised over here and tried all answers given but no success.

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    new_style_message: true,
    message: "is bringing you to the UPicnic !",
    display: "iframe"
},somefunction);
```

I have tried `new_style_message : true` for custom message which I have seen answered by few users and also referred in facebook dialog request documentation.

Still, I do not receive the custom message. Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`new_style_message` is not a valid parameter in Requests Dialog.

See documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/#redirect

And you can write any cutom message in `message` parameter.

```
FB.ui({
   method: 'apprequests',
   message: "this is my custom message",
   display: "iframe"
},somefunction);
```

---

**Direct Url**

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=262546773892944&message=custom%20message&%20%20redirect_uri=http://localhost/fb_test/

Comment: What do you mean by not working? I've added a direct url, you can clearly see the "Custom message"

Comment: When I invite my friend, custom message is not displayed in notification. It shows "Abhilasha invited you to try <appname>".

Comment: The `message` is not shown for requests that are _invites_ – this is _by design_. What you said it shows is how it is _supposed_ to be for invites.

Comment: Yes, as @CBroe said, that message is by design!

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the information. So is there any way to send customize message that invitees can receive.

Comment: That depends on your requirement. You can send the notification using Notifications API if you have a canvas app; and pf course if that suits your application